# how to create global variable in the sharepoint visual web part

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need a global variable like a session variable to access in the all the page in visual webpart. I don't want to use the list or library or session to do this. What is the best way to create a global variable in the sharepoint 2013 visual webpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways of sending information between pages in .Net:

Querystring - Don’t use Querystring to send protected information

HttpContext - Works only with Server.Transfer

Cookies - Don’t store secured information in cookies

Session - persisting secured information’s across pages

Read through [How to Pass Values from One Page to Another in ASP.Net?](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/351_How_to_Pass_Values_from_One_Page_to_Another_in_ASPNet.aspx) to give you a better understanding and help with your selection of which one to use.

Regards,

Vince

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is very useful information, but I am finding ways to use the sharepoint object model without the list and library.

Comment: I finally arrived session is the best way to use global variables.